# "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" when applying high order functions

Tags: python, function, closures

I've seen this method on a tutorial on how to enter two arguments differently on high order functions:

```
def def1(arg1):
  def def2(arg2):
      arg1 +' '+  arg2
  print(def2)
Holder = def1('Morgan')
Holder('Dexter')
```

Comment: `def1` needs to `return def2`

Comment: `def2` likely should return something also.

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot easier to understand higher order functions if you can be explicit about what each function takes as its argument and returns as its result.  Better names, docstrings, and type annotations all help a lot!

```
from typing import Callable

def name_generator(last_name: str) -> Callable[[str], str]:
  """Returns a function that returns full names for a given last name."""
  def full_name(first_name: str) -> str:
      """Returns the full name of a person with the given first name."""
      return first_name + ' ' + last_name
  return full_name

morgan_name = name_generator('Morgan')
print(morgan_name('Dexter'))  # prints "Dexter Morgan"
print(morgan_name('Debra'))   # prints "Debra Morgan"
```

If you wanted the function itself to do the printing, then the printing needs to happen inside the function that your higher-order function is returning, **not** inside the higher order function itself!

```
from typing import Callable

def name_printer(last_name: str) -> Callable[[str], None]:
  """Returns a function that prints full names for a given last name."""
  def print_name(first_name: str) -> None:
      """Prints the full name of a person with the given first name."""
      print(first_name + ' ' + last_name)
  return print_name

morgan_print = name_printer('Morgan')
morgan_print('Dexter')  # prints "Dexter Morgan"
morgan_print('Debra')   # prints "Debra Morgan"
```

Comment: Thanks. This is actually very helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

The `def1` function doesn't return anything (so it defaults to `None`). If you want `def1` to return the `def2` function, then you have to explicitly return it with `return def2` at the end.

```
def def1(arg1):
  def def2(arg2):
      arg1 +' '+  arg2
  return def2
Holder = def1('Morgan')
Holder('Dexter')
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd actually have to return the content on def2 too to actually get it to work.